# Synchronize jobs

Tags: prolog

I have two function ;

```
  foo ( A, B, C ) 

  bar ( D, E, F )
```

I want ;

```
 | --------- |
foo         foo 
started    finished

             | -------  |
            bar        bar 
          started    finished

                        | ------ |
                        ^^^^^^^^^^
                         concatenate two list namely C and F
```

How can I synchronize these two functions in order to work as in order ?

Can you give a sample example ?

Answer (score 1):

```
foo(A,B,C), bar(D,E,F), append(C,F,Result).
```